# Specify Bounding Box Region with pytesseract or OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract

Is it possible to specify a specific bounding box region of a PNG to be OCR'ed when using pytesseract? The pytesseract docs are sparse and it looks like pytesseract.image_to_boxes only returns bounding box values of identified text.

I have a large PNG image, and what I want to do is only OCR a specific region of that page by specifying a bounding box region. I think this can be done with OpenCV but I haven't yet found any examples.

Thanks in advance